# Trouble creating archive for project with my static library

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, arm64

I am developing a static library for iOS, now I am testing my static library (libXYZ.a) with a test project, I am able to run it on device but when I am trying
to make archive of the test project I got some errors saying:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Ravindra/Desktop/SDK Project/Static Library/XYZSDKTest/XYZSDKTest/XYZ_SDK/libXYZSDK.a, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/Ravindra/Desktop/SDK Project/Static Library/XYZSDKTest/XYZSDKTest/XYZ_SDK/libXYZSDK.a (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XYZ", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XYZConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I used the following command to build universal build:

```
lipo -create "libXYZSDK_simulator.a" "libXYZSDK_device.a" -output "libXYZSDK.a"
```

Please help me out to resolve this problem.

Comment: did you select 'Release' before build your Static Library in project's Scheme?like: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hvpeH.png

Comment: Have you checked target membership ?

Comment: Setting the "Build for active architecture only" to NO solved my problem.